# Overall formatting in LyX

Tags: spacing, formatting, lyx

I could not find a previous question that dealt with this topic, and much of the guidance is one-off.

I am creating a paper and I want the text to be double spaced but not section headings, the title, tables, nor the references. Is there is a global preamble item that deals with this? I am assuming that this is a popular request.

Additionally, the double spacing in LyX seems small, specially when compared to MS Word. Is the latter wrong, if not is there a way to fix this in LyX, without affecting non-body text items?

The only thing that helps with the section spacing is:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\singlespacing}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\singlespacing}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\singlespacing}
```

I find though that this fixes one problem, the title is now single spaces, but adds extra white space directly above the section headings.

Comment: What about my previous suggestion (using [Double-spaced paragraphs, single-spaced headers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106468/5764)) doesn't work? Did you include the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) in your preamble? Did you wrap the commands inside `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`?

Comment: @Werner Hasn't helped in using LyX. Things like my tables have extra spacing. All I want is body text to be double, everything else single. I am hoping to avoid ERT.

Comment: I see, so your question now is more general then (as it includes the ToC, amongst other things). Most likely you won't need ERTs, but your LaTeX preamble will be filled with LaTeX awesomeness to accommodate for this requirement (and is therefore not limited to LyX, per se). Although it might seem like "a popular request" to you, everybody has their own motivation for doing things, and therefore popular is very subjective.

Comment: @Werner Agreed, I am hoping someone can help. Mostly, I find that LyX double spacing is a little short (not a huge deal), but I would like my tables not to be as spaced. And my section titles not being spaced.

Comment: About the spacing compared with MS Word, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/number-of-lines-in-double-spacing-compared-to-word).

Comment: @Fran Thanks, very helpful. Now if I could stop it front affecting the headers

Comment: With respect the tables: Inside a float (a `table` environment = `Insert > Float  > Table`) a table (a `tabular` environment = `Insert > Table`) is **not** affected by the a double spacing set  in the preamble or in the body text (only when is set inside the float).