# Double-spaced paragraphs with single-spaced headers in classicthesis?

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing, classicthesis, setspace

I've been writing my PhD thesis using the `classicthesis` template with the `arsclassica` style package. My university requires that I double-space the body of the thesis, so I'm using `\doublespacing` for most of the document. This has the annoying effect of double-spacing my chapter and section headings as well. I could manually insert `\singlespacing` before and `\doublespacing` after every chapter/section/subsection heading, but this would be very tedious.

I'm aware of several previous answers on this topic, in particular [this one from @GonzaloMedina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106469/76837), which suggests two possible remedies:

1. Use `etoolbox` to insert `\singlespacing` before, and `\doublespacing` after, each sectional unit:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \pretocmd{\@sect}{\singlespacing}{}{}
   \pretocmd{\@ssect}{\singlespacing}{}{}
   \apptocmd{\@sect}{\doublespacing}{}{}
   \apptocmd{\@ssect}{\doublespacing}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any effect for `classicthesis` documents.
2. Use `titlesec` to specify the formatting of the headings directly:

   ```
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \titleformat{\section}
   {\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
   \titleformat{\subsection}
   {\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
   \titleformat{\subsubsection}
   {\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
   ```

   However, this overrides the nice default formatting provided by `arsclassica`/`classicthesis`.

In the comments section under that question, @PeterGrill suggests using

```
\let\OldSection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{\singlespace\OldSection{#1}\doublespace}
```

This is the closest I currently have to a working solution, but it unfortunately prevents me from using the optional `\section[Short title]{Long title}` syntax, which would be useful for some of my long section headings. He also suggested another variant to address this:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\OldSection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}[2][]{\singlespace\OldSection[#1]{#2}\doublespace}
```

But, as Gonzalo pointed out, this prevents the TOC from being generated correctly.

In short, I'd like to know whether there is a better way to specifically enforce single spacing for chapter/section/subsection headings within an otherwise double-spaced document that uses `classicthesis`/`arsclassica`.

---

Below is a simple test-case:

```
\documentclass[headinclude, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\section[A short section name]{A long section name that spans multiple lines within the document but should be single-spaced}
\lipsum[1]
\section[Another short section name]{Another long section name that spans multiple lines within the document but should be single-spaced}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redo the relevant `\titleformat` command:

```
\documentclass[headinclude, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\singlespacing}
  {\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}
  {1em}
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps}


\begin{document}
\doublespacing

\section[A short section name]{A long section name that spans multiple lines within the document but
should be single-spaced}

\lipsum[1]

\section[Another short section name]{Another long section name that spans multiple lines within the
document but should be single-spaced}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

With or without `arsclassica` is the same.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Out of interest, do you know why does the `etoolbox` approach doesn't work?

Comment: @ali_m Since `classicthesis` uses `titlesec`, there are several layers added and `\@sect` is “almost unreachable”.

Comment: Ah, I see - so does that mean I have no option but to define my own `\titleformat` for each type of heading I want to use? What you've provided looks great, but I was hoping that there would be a more generic way to enforce single-spacing without having to specify anything else about the formatting.

Comment: @ali_m As I said, `classicthesis` uses quite an involved method for setting the headings; just look in the code and add `\singlespacing` to the `\titleformat` instructions where there's `\relax`, similar to the code I showed.

Comment: Thanks - your comments pushed me towards trying to better understand how the template works, and I'm now convinced that the simplest option is probably just to add `\singlespacing` to `arsclassica.sty` where appropriate.