# Single-space chapter titles with double-spaced document

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

I am typesetting a thesis using the `book` class and need the chapter titles to be single-spaced while the main text must be double-spaced.

Inserting `\singlespacing` before the text in the definition of the chapter creates `! Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible` errors on compiling, and also inserts a spurious newline between the chapter numbers and names in the table of contents.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % included only to generate example text
\usepackage{setspace} % set double vs single spacing
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\doublespacing
\chapter{I need singlespace titles, doublespace text.}
\section{Section headers should also be single-spaced, but I could adjust titles to fit on one line}
\lipsum[4] % generate some filler text
\end{document}
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106468/double-spaced-paragraphs-single-spaced-headers), as the answers to that question involve either specific hacks to the `\section` commands, or the `titlesec` package which gives the error `! Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in 'easy' settings.` when I attempt to use it with the `book` class.

Edit: it turns out that `sectsty` is unsuitable for my needs as it disrupts formatting elsewhere and interacts with `doublespacing` differently than using the `titlesec` solution. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace} % set double vs single spacing
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\chapter{Singlespace titles, doublespace text.}
\section{Section headers should \\also be single-spaced}
\subsubsection{The \texttt{sectsty} package interacts with \texttt{doublespacing}, adds too much space below this header}
\paragraph{The \texttt{sectsty} package causes this paragraph to be indented}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice that in my answer `sectsty` is loaded after `setspace`; this is not the case in your updated example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106468/double-spaced-paragraphs-single-spaced-headers) has a solution for section headings using the `titlesec` package. However, if this answer is copied and naïvely modified for chapter headings, it will result in a `! Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in 'easy' settings` error. The error arises because the [titlesec package works a little differently with chapters than it does sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/how-to-adjust-the-size-and-placement-of-chapter-heading-in-report-class). An incantation to single-space chapters and section headers using the `titlesec` package is as follows:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\singlespacing}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add the following instructions to the document's preamble (after loading the `setspace` package):

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I need singlespace titles, doublespace text.}

\section{Section headers should also be single-spaced, but I could adjust titles to fit on one line}

\lipsum[4] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This sectsty package is very handy and I think should be added as an  answer to these two questions [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106468/double-spaced-paragraphs-single-spaced-headers) [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/how-to-adjust-the-size-and-placement-of-chapter-heading-in-report-class)

Comment: @MRule - Thanks for this suggestion; I've provided an answer that mentions the `sectsty` package in the first of the two posting's you've provided links to. The second is about issues with the `titlesec` package, and `sectsty` doesn't directly address these issues.

Comment: Apologies, it turns out the `sectsty` package interacts poorly with some of my other formatting needs. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @MRule - Please provide specifics about the "poor interactions".