# Trouble with \titlespacing: automatically generated \hypertarget and \label when converting from markdown may interfere with title

Tags: biblatex, pandoc

See below for my MWE.

I'm trying to change the spacing around titles, so I put in the \titlespacing package and that works sometimes. However, when converting from markdown to .tex with pandoc the titles are surrounded by a hypertarget and a label and these may be interfering:

```
\hypertarget{speaking-from-power-ventriloquism-and-its-role-in-american-colonialism}{%
\section{this is a longer title that has a bunch of words and includes a line break or three}\label{speaking-from-power-ventriloquism-and-its-role-in-american-colonialism}}
```

when I remove everything but `\section{...}` it seems to work.

Also these two things seem to be bothering the function to not indent the very first paragraph of a chapter/subchapter.

How can I fix this? I would like the heading to be spaced a bit from the preceding text, but less so from the coming text, and the line spacing of titles/headings should be smaller.

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[]{nohyperref}

%% HEADINGS <-------------------------------------------
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}  % <--------------------

% HEADINGS & SECTIONS%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

% SECTION NUMBERING %
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering


\setlength{\parindent}{5em}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2mm} % shrinks gap between footnotes

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}


\setlength{\parindent}{5em}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}


% START DOCUMENT %
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2mm} % shrinks gap between footnotes

\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagenumbering{roman}




% START BODY %

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}

\section{this is a longer title that has a bunch of words and includes a line break or three}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec nisl nec sapien lobortis fringilla. Suspendisse placerat varius justo eget sollicitudin. Morbi luctus, justo ut pharetra fermentum, eros eros feugiat risus, nec egestas ex ipsum non libero. Vestibulum et tincidunt diam, vel bibendum mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce scelerisque in ante nec pretium. Quisque a felis ante. Suspendisse et cursus nibh, ac luctus magna. Mauris congue id magna vitae tempus. Praesent a ligula a purus accumsan sodales. Nam quis venenatis lorem. Proin pulvinar odio in mollis ultricies. Pellentesque pretium, eros at cursus malesuada, velit ex fermentum risus, quis vestibulum ante orci in eros. Praesent mi ligula, fringilla id mi sed, lobortis elementum quam. In consectetur quam urna, eu semper massa pharetra in. Mauris finibus dignissim pulvinar.

Curabitur nec pretium libero. Nulla facilisi. Praesent maximus eros enim, eu aliquet libero accumsan quis. Etiam hendrerit dictum tincidunt. Aliquam scelerisque vitae eros sed dictum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec aliquam ut velit eu scelerisque. Duis non vestibulum purus.
Curabitur nec pretium libero. Nulla facilisi. Praesent maximus eros enim, eu aliquet libero accumsan quis. Etiam hendrerit dictum tincidunt. Aliquam scelerisque vitae eros sed dictum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec aliquam ut velit eu scelerisque. Duis non vestibulum purus.
\subsection{a long subheading that also includes one line break}
Vestibulum accumsan dolor in lorem tincidunt elementum nec id enim. Sed tortor lacus, volutpat quis ornare sit amet, consequat ut turpis. Ut ac vehicula magna. Aliquam sit amet porttitor justo, vel gravida est. Cras ornare enim quis sapien dictum, sit amet convallis nisl dignissim. Suspendisse non lectus eget arcu accumsan luctus in sit amet ex. Maecenas gravida eget dolor ornare facilisis. Sed vitae viverra ipsum.

Ut auctor, elit quis molestie lacinia, odio ante ullamcorper massa, sed interdum odio massa ut neque. Aenean id libero interdum, hendrerit urna eu, volutpat libero. Vivamus interdum purus non aliquam posuere. Aliquam molestie tortor blandit ante tincidunt, at hendrerit magna hendrerit. Nam tempus eleifend neque, nec blandit velit varius non. Nam accumsan arcu ut nibh placerat, a rhoncus purus gravida. Etiam nisi dolor, tempor ut dui eget, aliquet iaculis massa. Cras ut massa lacus. Cras elementum elit non nisi efficitur euismod. Curabitur nulla lorem, porttitor id efficitur eget, laoreet et orci. Nam eu semper lacus, maximus imperdiet odio. Nulla pellentesque, mauris at consectetur elementum, odio felis volutpat mi, sed accumsan magna purus ut turpis. Phasellus ultricies tristique elit nec semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Phasellus viverra libero non nunc euismod, at ultricies sem viverra. Integer sed elit ut nisi dignissim dictum.

Sed sagittis nunc non velit cursus, ac rhoncus ex interdum. Suspendisse scelerisque, nisi vel vehicula suscipit, metus est interdum tortor, nec vulputate magna nibh non sapien. Praesent in diam blandit, ornare urna ut, scelerisque augue. Donec hendrerit finibus pretium. Mauris maximus urna et libero iaculis, id mattis arcu malesuada. Sed consequat eros a dolor venenatis gravida. Maecenas vel feugiat massa, nec hendrerit ante. Suspendisse elementum augue in euismod suscipit. Proin elementum ipsum nisi, sed lacinia quam tempus et. Morbi eu libero enim. Vestibulum tempus vel augue quis convallis. Morbi nec elit faucibus, posuere elit sed, finibus lacus. Sed cursus neque ac nunc ullamcorper gravida. Sed vel ultrices nunc. Vestibulum vulputate enim ipsum, et sodales eros maximus nec. Maecenas posuere risus ut odio vulputate, nec pretium tellus aliquam. 


\begin{center}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}\end{center}
\end{spacing}



\clearpage



\end{document}
\makeatother
```

Comment: complain to pandoc. This hypertarget is unneeded and nonsense.

Comment: OK, so I found this, added it, and now I think it works: `-r markdown-auto_identifiers -w latex` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352448/17505879
Except that the line spacing in headings are still huge. How can I change this?

Comment: you could start by making a proper complete and *minimal* example, I have neither the will nor the time to wade through all this to remove the irrelevant code.

Comment: okey dokey, edited the example

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 Is this a MWE of your problem? `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{2}
\section{this is a longer title that has a bunch of words and includes a line break or three}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}`

Comment: If that's what you are asking about, then try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291382/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yup, that did it. Thanks!!

Comment: It does, thanks :)